# Use 4 pole combo jack as mono/stereo input

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, audio-recording, jack-audio

I have a HP laptop (recent 15" Pavilion) with a "combo" headset jack, that serves as a stereo headphones output and a mono microphone input. My question is, *without any external adapters*, would it be possible to get Windows to recognise a connected mono (TS) or stereo (TRS) cable as an audio input? Or is it impossible due to the design of the jack and the ADC/DACs? I'm open to solutions using any kind of Windows software (I'm running Windows 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The microphone is connected to the sleeve and middle ring (ground), and the headphone is connected to the tip and first ring.  Without an adapter, you won't have an electrical connection between the microphone and the computer.  In fact the microphone will be connected to the headset output for the left channel, and the computer's microphone signal will be connected to the ground pin.

You will need an adapter to connect and unmodified cable.